# How to render a backbone collection into two views

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am using twitter bootstrap link. When the user clicks the link a bootstrap modal appears.
Now because of some bootstrap technical difficulties in modal rendering i need to seperate the link and put the modal out the navbar div.

So consider i have two separate div

```
                      <div id="linkDiv">

                      </div>
```

and

```
                      <div id="modalDiv">

                      </div>
```

Now i have only one View which makes a call to the server to get the collection

```
app.View.FriendRequestListView = Backbone.View.extend( {
templateModalLink: _.template($('#link').html()),
templateModal: _.template($('#modal').html()),

tagName: 'div',

initialize: function(){
    this.friendRequestCollection = new app.Collection.FriendRequestCollection();
    this.friendRequestCollection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    this.friendRequestCollection.fetch();
},

render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.templateModalLink({
        friendRequestCollection: this.friendRequestCollection}));
    return $(this.el);
},
 });
```

Than i can render only one div like following

```
var list = new app.View.FriendRequestListView();
  $('#linkDiv').html(list.$el);
```

My question is , Is it possible to render two templates at the same time and add the two templates to different DIV like for example in my case i want to get update 
templateModalLink template to linkDiv and templateModal template to modalDiv with the collection I am getting from the server.

Comment: could you please elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to instantiate the collection before app.View.FriendRequestListView(s) and pass app.View.FriendRequestListView(s) the collection:

```
var friendRequests = new app.Collection.FriendRequestCollection();
friendRequests.fetch(
    success: function(collection, response, options) {
        var list1 = new app.View.FriendRequestListView({collection: collection});
        var list2 = new app.View.FriendRequestListView({collection: collection});

        $('#linkDiv').html(list1.$el);
        $('#modalDiv').html(list2.$el);
    }
);
```